# Print list without brackets using f string

Tags: python

Title says it all. I have a list with some values and I want to print them so that the brackets don't show up. I know I can use print(*value) but that doesn't work when using f-strings. To illustrate my point:

```
print(f'This list contains: {function_that_returns_list()}')
```

I've been looking for an answer for hours so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
print(f'This list contains: {" ".join(function_that_returns_list())}')
```

Comment: This does not work.  I have a list in a variable, not calling a function, but I don't think that matters.  I get various exceptions depending on how I fuss with this expression. Are there hidden assumptions being made?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just chop off the first and last character in the `str` result, representing the start and close brackets? Brief example below:

```py
L = ['1', '2', '3']

print(f'This list contains: {str(L)[1:-1]}')
```

Out:

```
This list contains: '1', '2', '3'
```

Comment: YAY! Works great. One little glitch though, is sometimes I get "string indices must be integers" using an expression inside { } as shown.  If I do the stringify and chop in an assignment to a variable first, then just have {x} in the f-string, then it's ok.  But then again, I could be doing something stupid not realizing it.